# How to get the sub tensor from a tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

```
label = tf.constant([0,1,2,3,4,4,5,5])
```

I have a tensor, for example, above one.
I want to filter the tensor where the element is 4. The output tensor should be [4,4].
How to realize it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `tf.where` to get the indices where a condition is true, and `tf.gather` to collect the specified values

```
import tensorflow as tf

label = tf.constant([0,1,2,3,4,4,5,5])
filtered = tf.gather(label, tf.where(tf.equal(label, 4)))
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(filtered))
```

> [[4]
>    [4]]

Comment: How to get the count of elements that is on the condition. For example, get the count of 4, which should return 2.  Any function to realize it ?

Comment: You should mark this answer as accepted and open a new one for new questions... however `filtered = tf.reduce_sum(tf.bincount(filtered))`